# ASP.Net MVC ajax always return error (issues with routing)

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I wrote simple form, which have simple form with button. Onclick with javascript method on this button should fire a ajax which should go to '/Parser/GetParseData'. But I always got error without any detail (always run request.fail).

I don't know what is problem. General My aim is fire ajax with data from form and after success (and getting answer) I want to put received string in $('#result').

Could you help me?

Ok my View:

```
@using Project.Domain.Entities
@model ParserHelper

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Project";
}
<h2>simple form asp.net mvc 5</h2><br/>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<fieldset>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(Model => Model.InputData)
    </div>
    <div class="radio-field">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.TypeOfResult, "xml") @Html.Label("Xml") <br/>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.TypeOfResult, "csv") @Html.Label("Csv")
    </div>
    <button onclick="submitTest()">Request!</button>
</fieldset>
}

<div id="result">
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
        function submitAlert() {
            alert("testtest");
        }

        function submitTest() {
            event.preventDefault();

            var data = {
                InputData: $('#InputData').val(),
                TypeOfResult: $('#TypeOfResult').val()
            };

            request = $.ajax({
                url: "/Parser/GetParseData",
                type: "post",
                formData: data
            });

            request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert("Hooray, it worked!");
                $('#result').text('Its worked:' + response);
            });

            request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(
                    "The following error occurred: " +
                    textStatus, errorThrown
                );
                $('#result').text('Sorry, error');
            });
        }
</script>
```

My model is:

```
public class ParserHelper : IFormHelper
{
    public string ResultAfterParse { get; set; }

    public string InputData { get; set; }

    public string TypeOfResult { get; set; }
}
```

Finally here is my controller metho in: ParserController : Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string GetParseData(IFormHelper formData)
{
    return "ANSWER!!!";
}
```

I also added this as Routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "PostData",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Parser", action = "GetParseData"  
});
```

If you need any more information let me know - I will edit this post.

SOLVED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your POST method signature needs to be

```
public string GetParseData(ParserHelper formData)
```

You cannot use an `interface` as a parameter. The `DefaultModelBinder` initializes objects using `Activator.CreateInstance()` and an `interface` cannot be initialized, only its concrete types.

Comment: But I use IOC Container - I mean Ninject. Even so I have to put strong typped var?

Comment: Yes (unless you were to create your own custom ModelBinder)

Answer (score 1):

If the error is **404 not found**, then the problem could the URL is not correct because of the hard-coding the URL which fails mostly if client side code is moved to a separate js file which resides in some sub folder in that case the path of URL becomes invalid, you should be using `Url.Action` method to generate the correct url like:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetParseData","Parser")'
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried that - but it doesn't help. I only know that it is internal server error